# Access list of pnrs and remove from queue using Sabre soap api

Tags: soap, sabre

I am using QueueAccessLLSRQ to retrieve pnrs from a particular queue in Sabre. But when we access the queue, it returns only 999 pnrs, but the queuue has more than 5000 pnrs, I suppose this is limitation of Sabre.

I truly appreciate if someone can list the steps to retrieve all pnrs from queue including if the process has steps to remove pnrs from queue.

Appreciate your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are options to navigate through the queue using modifiers using QueueAccessLLSRQ (see the [Navigation Options here](http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/QueueAccessLLSRQ_v2.0.9_Design.xml)), so you could ostensibly build logic to first use the [QueueCountLLSRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/queue/get_queue_count/resources) to gather the number of PNRs in a given queue and then use the navigation modifiers in QueueAccessLLSRQ  to gather the list of PNRs using the navigation modifiers.

You'd have to make multiple calls to the QueueAccessLLSRQ API with the modifiers but it seems like that would work.

As far as removing PNRs from queue, I'm not sure what the best way to go about that would be, but the QueueAcessLLSRQ seems to support it - removing a PNR from queue uses the "QR" Action Code to remove a PNR from Queue.

I generally find it easier to gather a list of PNRs on a given queue, access the record outside of the queue, do whatever work I need to do in them, and then remove them from the target queue from the outside. The equivalent Sabre command to remove a PNR from a target queue while NOT on said queue is something like this:

QR/[PCC][Queue Number]

For Example, where PCC = 8KKY and Queue Number = 99:

QR/8KKY99